# python selenium driver.quit() won't terminate the program midway

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following section of the code suppose to terminate(stop) the program when except occurs, with `driver.quit()`. However, the program continues runs. what did I missed here?

```
try:
    driver.refresh()
    wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Move']")))
    print("Waiting for Move")
    time.sleep (1)
except:
    print("All Move Completed")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: wrap that `driver.quit()` again in try and except and see what exception you get.

Comment: Does your code reach this `except` and do you see the print message?

Comment: While anthino12 is relevant, could you also share the entire code that you've ? or is it simply a try and except block?

Comment: yes, I see the print message "All Move Completed", then it closes the chrome browser, but the code keeps running.

Comment: I saw your comment below, if it's wrapped in a while clause make sure you exit out of it. Do a `break` after `driver.quit()`

Comment: I tried `break` after `driver.quit()`, i got "SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop"

Comment: @JackLuo Please don't change the question based on which you have received well researched answers. Once you receive canonical answers changing the question can make all the existing answers invalid and may not be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. For the time being I have reverted back the question to it's initial state.

Comment: will do. thanks, I will try different approaches here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `driver.quit()` after `driver.close()` back to back.

Remove `driver.close()` totally. Simply keeping `driver.quit()` will do the job.

Your effective code block will be:

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.refresh()
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Move']")))
        print("Waiting for Move")
        continue
    except TimeoutException:
        break
print("All Move Completed")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: sorry, I meant to illustrate I tried both. simply have driver.quit() won't work either. the program continue runs.

Comment: I wonder if I should "break" the loop?

Comment: @JackLuo checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: **SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop**

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: thanks for the update. I've updated my original code to include more info for clarification. perhaps I should wrap my loops differently. I will try the while true method.